# How can I compare 2 columns in 2 tables to check for UNEQUAL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

I have a table say Table 1 with column A with values {22,18,17} and another table Table 2 with column B with values {18,22} when I do a query like

```
select * from Table 1 where column A not in (select column B in Table 2).
```

This gives me 3 rows {22,18,17}

I want only 17 as output.

I am newbie to SQL can anyone help me

Comment: I am using 2008 express edition

Comment: Thanks - and **please** for future questions: **always** provide those crucial bits of information right away, when you post the qusetion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as T2 on T1.ColumnA = T2.ColumnB
WHERE T2.T2ID IS NULL
```

Comment: This is not more efficient than `NOT IN` / `NOT EXISTS`. See http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/